# string parsing in linq query and use anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types, string-parsing

i have many objects like this:

```
 var obj4 = new Data { name = "person", date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), data = "pr-214-2-20151224-word2-word3" };
```

i want to write a linq query that result be this:

```
result=[name=person, date=04/09/2016 12:00:00 AM, data=[2,3]]//2 and 3 are the numbers after word
```

so far i tried this:

```
   var listak=new List<Data>{obj,obj2,obj3,obj4};
    var u = listak.OrderByDescending(s => s.date).TakeWhile(s => s.date > DateTime.Now).Select(s=>new
    {
        name=s.name,
        date=s.date,
        data=s.data.Split(new []{"-"},StringSplitOptions.None).Select(m=>new
        {
            word = m.Where(c=>m.StartsWith("word")).Select(c=>m.Remove(0,4))//this line is incorrect, i dont know how to correct this part
        })

    });
```

but i cant get what i want, how can i achieve that?

Comment: Your where clause needs to move out to operate on the result of string split. You want just the bits that start with "word".

Comment: @IanMercer yes, thanks, thats it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
   var obj4 = new { name = "person", date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), data = "pr-214-2-20151224-word2-word3" };
   var listak = new[] { obj4 }.ToList();
   var u = listak.OrderByDescending(s => s.date).TakeWhile(s => s.date > DateTime.Now).Select(s => new
   {
        name = s.name,
        date = s.date,
        data = s.data.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Where(c => c.StartsWith("word")).Select(m => m.Remove(0, 4))
    });

    Console.Write(u);
```

[image]